# Lost text file from jumplist

Tags: windows, notepad, jumplist

I am missing a text file.

The file was usually accessed via a pinned shortcut on a jumplist off of the Notepad shortcut on the taskbar. I don't remember where the actual file was stored.

The pinned file has disappeared and now I can't find the file.  I have searched the whole hard drive and not found any files with that name.

Comment: You could search the root of your hard drive for the file name. It takes a very long time but will (most likely) find it (unless it was on a different drive or deleted).

Comment: You may want to consider using a third-party utility called [Agent Ransack](https://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack/) to search your hard drive. It is (currently) free for home and commercial use, contains no adware and you can ignore the bit about "registration" for home use. Importantly, it does a brute force search that does not rely on file indexes (like other search utilities often do) and thus may be more likely to find the file your looking for.

Comment: I finally found the file by doing a mix of the suggestions here so thanks to all that answered.  The file was hiding in a subfolder of OneDrive; I don't remember ever using OneDrive!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you have made sure it is not hiding in the Recycle Bin?   Do you remember something from inside that file?

If so, let's look for the file by its content.

Hit the Start icon, type “index,” and then click the “Indexing Options” result.

In the “Indexing Options” window, click the “Advanced” button.

The “Advanced Options” window is where you switch to the “File Types” tab. Choose the extension for the file type you would like to include in content searches (TXT?), then (IMPORTANT!) pick the “Index Properties and File Contents” item. The text in the “Filter Description” column should change to reflect whatever filter is used to open that file type by default. If you choose the TXT extension, the filter type changes to “Plain Text.”

Now, the index will rebuild, then the search for a text string inside one of the new file types should soon show results.

If you have a backup of the C: drive from before the disappearance, the jump list items should be in C:\Users[Username]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations